# ActionScript: code for finding mac address doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following code in Actions of a keyframe in Adobe Flash Professional CS6:

```
var networkInterface : Object =  NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
var networkInfo  : Object = networkInterface[0];
var physicalAddress : String = networkInfo.hardwareAddress.toString();
```

When I hit Ctrl+Enter to run the movie, I get the following compiler error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 2, Line 1 1120: Access of undefined property NetworkInfo.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you import the right classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add:

```
import flash.net.NetworkInfo;
```

and in publish settings you must chose Adobe AIR rather than flash player

Comment: It works, thanks, although it seems import is not necessary and I don't understand why the target had to be changed.

Comment: Air is more powerful than flash player, some system info can't be retrieved by the simple flash player.