# MAC BAN people in a Flash game

Tags: flash, memory-management, mac-address

My name is CM Sulaco, I am a community manager at [Kixeye Gaming](https://www.kixeye.com/) (War Commander)
We have ran into a lot of trouble with cheaters using [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) (Memory Modifier) and similar tools.

I am inquiring as to whether there is a way to MAC ban a player who cheats, if so how would this be achieved in a Adobe Flash game?

Thanks for any help given!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function that fires when someone is caught cheating, you could [try something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376537/actionscript-code-for-finding-mac-address-doesnt-work) [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794493/get-unique-identifier-mac-address-udid-etc-in-adobe-air-for-ios) to get the user's MAC address when they cheat, and send it to a table in a database, and subsequently kick them, and ban the user.

Something like this could work:

```
CREATE TABLE `bannedUsers` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `macAddress` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `cheatInstance` varchar(19) NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE `bannedUsers`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `bannedUsers`
MODIFY `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Then, when the user/s login, the system could search the database for a matching MAC address.

```
SELECT * FROM `bannedUsers` WHERE `macAddress`='(hacker mac address here)';
```

And then do a count on whether the row count returned is zero.